# In ubuntu alt+f2 spawns a process that is not attached to a shell. How would I do that in bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

```
emacs &
```

Forks but the process is attached to the shell

```
nohup emacs &
```

Something like that works but seems to make some kind of log file

Just what exactly is alt+f2 doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you start a background process with `&` you can use the builtin `disown` to detach it from the shell and let it run detached.  That is also more or less what `nohup` does, save the log being associated.

In essence, Alt-F2 starts a process and disowns it.